# Ssas cube data not coming for two months?

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am new to SSAS. We have a cube that has been working fine for more than two years but data for Dec 2017 and this month (Feb 2018) only is not showing up. Why would the data stop showing up for these two teo months only!

Can someone let me know what I need to check?

Comment: Check he data source for that cube. And execute particular script (view/table) where cube is referencing. You will get idea why it is not coming.

Comment: datasource tested no issues and cube refresh without any errors but data not coming for these two months...!